# setState in neasted array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I wish to update particular input value, I suceeded to do so with one dimensional array but unfortunatelly in my case 2d is necessary and I have no idea how to do so as I tried already all combinations of rows and cells.

Here is link to demo -> https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-mirzakhani-46exz?file=/src/App.js

Basically, thing is that after typing some value to for example X-axis in first row, I wish only this field value to be updated. I have button which can add new row to inputValue which contains all input titles, and contents.
Another thing is that if I write something to the input now, it transforms aray into object and because of that app crash

Comment: Is your goal here to make instance of your chunkingRow and store them in an array that will generate a table?

Comment: Please review hooks and the setting state as well. As here you are mutating the value incorrectly. The reason for which is you are accessing the value returned from the  closure rather than use the function to mutate that is included instead.

Comment: my goal is that each input has it's own value called "content" I want to modify content which belongs to particular input, basically each input onChange is modifying itself by handleChunkingChange

Comment: Okay give me a few minutes please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so you had a few issues going on here, but overall it was a good effort!

1. You were attempting to update the state directly instead of using the mutation function provided by array destruction and hooks
2. In the state update, you were not merging objects properly leading to the same value to be passed
3. You were not using props properly

To address these I made a new input component that tracks each component row and col inside its props. Then these values will be used alongside the prop drilled mutation function and retrieved content value from your chunk component.

Please let me know if this is not working

Below is a link to the working version, please look at the console to see the updates and there is a button that will print the current value of inputValue for you as well. State now also updates as you enter.

Edit: I have addressed your comment and fixed the example so that it follows your request. I went ahead and switched to using the useReducer hook instead now as it makes the logic a little easier to understand and to read in my opinion. Feel free to try to figure it out with useState too, if you wanted to do that. For now, though here is the link again:
 https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-resonance-wokey?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: oh seems like problem was more complicated than i thought, thank you so much for help:) it works however with current shape I can't add anymore rows as before in Chunk was button like ```<button
      onClick={() =>
        setInputValue((prevInputValute) => [...prevInputValute, chunkingRow])
      }
    >``` and now it shows that prevInputValue is not iteratable, also I see that there is ```tmp[0][row][cell]["content"] = value;``` which indicated to already existing row. What if I add another rows later as that's the idea to be able to create many rows?

Comment: I guess making inputValue as a object might to not work as I won't be able to push anymore rows and it's essential that user can add as many rows as he wants

Comment: Oh um okay give me some more time and I will make the adjustments. I just saw these comments.

Comment: Did these changes fix your concerns?

Comment: whoaa looks complex but hmm understandable, issue I had turned out to be much more complex than I would imagine, Thank you so very much for your time and help! I doubt I could achieve it on my own:) Huge thanks!

Comment: Of course, happy to help and I hope you learned something along the way too. Good luck with your endeavours with react. :)